# My if statement isn't looping properly in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ive only done 1 semester of python, but this looks like it should be working and im all out of ideas!!! Basically I need to create a 10 question quiz that asks the questions in random order, the issue i face is that the loop only acknowledges the 1st question and doesn't move through all 10

```
import random
questions = ["2x2", "4x4", "3x3", "5x5", "0x100", "6x2", "10x10", "5x7", 
"9x8" ,"9x9"]
questions2 = ["Question 1", "Question 2", "Question 3", "Question 4", 
"Question 5", "Question 6", "Question 7", "Question 8", "Question 9" 
,"Question 10"]
num1 = [2, 4, 3, 5, 0, 6, 10, 5, 9, 9]
num2 = [2, 4, 3, 5, 100, 2, 10, 7, 8, 9]
ans = [4, 16, 9, 25, 0, 12, 100, 35, 75, 81]
random.randint(0,9)
random.shuffle(questions)
question2 = 0
question = 0
while question < 10:
    print ((questions2[question]), (questions[question]))
    user_typed_ans= int(input())
    if user_typed_ans==num1[0]* num2[0]:
        print ("Correct")
    else:
        print ("Incorrect:")
        print(ans[0])
    question += 1
```

Comment: Well, doesn't `[0]` look suspicious? If you want other values, don't always use the first index

Comment: Also, instead of `questions2`, why aren't you just using `print("Question " + question)`?

Comment: It loops through for me. Of course it wasn't acknowledging my correct answers though.

Answer (score 0):

Use correct indices for answer checking:

```
import random

questions = ["2x2", "4x4", "3x3", "5x5", "0x100", "6x2", "10x10", "5x7", "9x8" ,"9x9"]
questions2 = ["Question 1", "Question 2", "Question 3", "Question 4", 
"Question 5", "Question 6", "Question 7", "Question 8", "Question 9" 
,"Question 10"]
num1 = [2, 4, 3, 5, 0, 6, 10, 5, 9, 9]
num2 = [2, 4, 3, 5, 100, 2, 10, 7, 8, 9]
ans = [4, 16, 9, 25, 0, 12, 100, 35, 75, 81]

# Comment this for correct answers
# random.shuffle(questions)

question = 0
while question < 10:
    print ((questions2[question]), (questions[question]))
    user_typed_ans = int(input())
    if user_typed_ans == num1[question] * num2[question]:
        print ("Correct")
    else:
        print ("Incorrect:")
        print (ans[question])
    question += 1
```

Comment: I have it working mostly, but now its repeating the same questions where i need it to only ask them once.

Comment: Remove `random.shuffle(questions)` (or comment it), for correct sequence.